# CNAME not working

Tags: dns, cname

I've a domain name on dot.tk which is noorani.tk. My blog is running on nooranibakerally-noor.rhcloud.com. As such, I want to noorani.tk for my blog. I believe this is a cname.

What I'm doing is going on dot.tk DNS service and adding a cname for noorani.tk,

where hostname= nooranibakerally-noor.rhcloud.com and ip address = 54.196.127.21.

Is this fine because when I'm adding it, the DNS service is returning this error message:

```
There was an error in the values you entered. Please check.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The root of the domain cannot be a CNAME because then it couldn't have NS/SOA records – there already are several posts explaining this.

Comment: I've re-read the question and existing answer, but I still don't understand the question as it is worded.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a CNAME that way. Each domain has to have its own authority record and nameservers, so it can't be an alias for something else.

How would you determine if the CNAME entry was still valid? You can't check the CNAME record itself because you don't know that it's valid. And you can't follow the CNAME to check because you don't know it's valid. It can't possibly work that way.

A CNAME must be a host located inside a domain. It cannot be the domain itself.